# Convert string to float? (image classification)

Tags: python, image, conv-neural-network, classification, preprocessor

```
'''   path = glob.glob("content/output/*.jpg")
  cv_img = []
  for img in path:
  n = cv.imread(img)
  cv_img.append(n)
  xd= cv_img[1:241:] 
   xd=np.array(xd).reshape(240,373248) 
    xd=pd.DataFrame(xd) 
   xd['data'] = xd[xd.columns[0:]].apply( lambda x: 
    ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1 ) 
    dat= xd.iloc[:,373248] 
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dat,labels, 
 test_size=0.33)

  X_test=(X_test.astype(np.float32)/255)
   X_train=(X_train.astype(np.float32)/255)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
'255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
```

I am getting this error when I try to convert image data to float for classification purposes. How can I do that?

Comment: The real problem is not at those lines. The real problem is that `X_test` and `X_train` are parsed as strings instead of floats in the first place. Please edit your post to include the loading/creating process of those variables and any modifications you are doing to them.

Comment: This is how I created them.>>>>X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dat,labels, test_size=0.33)/// dat is a Series >>>xd= cv_img[1:241:]
xd=np.array(xd).reshape(240,373248)
xd=pd.DataFrame(xd)
xd['data'] = xd[xd.columns[0:]].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1
)
dat= xd.iloc[:,373248]

Comment: sure, but that isn't very helpful. How is `dat` created, then? What I mean is the initial parsing of your data (from whatever source they are stored) has some problem since they end up being treated as strings. Please edit **your post** to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code snippet  (not as a comment). This will help you get a resolution in your problem. Right now, we can only guess

Comment: from the above lines, it seems like your problem comes from applying that `lambda`: `','.join(...)` will return a string. Essentially you are converting each row of `xd` to a single string of comma-separated values which would explain your error. What would this line do? Remove NaNs? There are better ways to do it in a pd.DataFrame

Comment: please see the above the part of code related this.